# How to ignore faulty mouse double click?

Tags: drivers, kernel, hardware, configuration

Probably my mouse has reached it's EOL. So, whenever I press left click once, most of the times it double clicks. I know changing the mouse is the easiest thing to do but, I was wondering if there is any way by which I can set time interval between to consecutive clicks to decide whether second click should be considered or not.

I just measured my speed of double clicking and found the average time interval between two clicks is nearly 0.11-0.12 seconds. So any click who's time interval is less than 0.08 seconds from previous click should be ignored.

Will this need to make a kernel module or will this require to make changes in driver source code.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings → Universal Access and set the Double Click delay there.

[image]

Adjust the slider to suit your preference.

If on the other hand you are seeking to apply a single click then refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516799/how-to-enable-single-click)

Comment: My question is completely different. This solution will work only for elements registered for double click event, e.g. you double click on an icon on desktop to launch any application. Your solution works in this situation. But In my case, suppose there are two windows on top of each other. If I try to close the top window, the window behind will also get closed because close button needs only single click. So both windows get closed.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect to find any software to deal with such a hardware issue. Your best bet is to work around it by using a combination of

- Keyboard shortcuts such as Ctrl+W to close windows & many others to deal with common tasks.
- Using mouse right-click on links to both open up the context menu & select the menu item (Tested to work on Chrome)
- Changing the mouse settings to left-handed which should swap the left & right mouse buttons, making right-click function as a left-click
- Using Keyboard Mouse Emulation to control the pointer with numpad . This is usually found under Keyboard or Accessibility settings depending on the desktop environment used .